# Mybatis and invalid types

Tags: java, postgresql, persistence, mybatis

I use mybatis 3.2.2,  PostgreSQL and get the "Error instantiating class xxx with invalid types or values". The exception is triggered when calling **getPluginId()**. Here is my configuration:

mapper.xml:

```
<resultMap type="my.class.plugins.Plugin" id="pluginMap">
    <constructor>
        <idArg column="id" javaType="_int"/>
        <arg column="dtype" javaType="String"/>
    </constructor>

</resultMap>
```

and this a problematic method:

```
<select id="getPluginById" resultMap="pluginMap">
SELECT *
FROM public.plugin
WHERE id = #{id, jdbcType=NUMERIC}
</select>
```

a default constructor:

```
public abstract class Plugin {
...
public Plugin(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

an the exception:

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Error instantiating class my.class.plugins.Plugin with invalid types (int,String,) or values (7418,FORWARD,). Cause: java.lang.InstantiationException
at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:73)
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:364)
at $Proxy15.selectOne(Unknown Source)
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectOne(SqlSessionTemplate.java:159)
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:63)
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:43)
at $Proxy16.getPluginById(Unknown Source)
at my.class.service.UserServiceImpl.getUserById(UserServiceImpl.java:44)
at my.class.persistence.db.DbUserDaoTest.testLoading(DbUserDaoTest.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Error instantiating class my.class.plugins.Plugin with invalid types (int,String,) or values (7418,FORWARD,). Cause: java.lang.InstantiationException
at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.instantiateClass(DefaultObjectFactory.java:83)
at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.create(DefaultObjectFactory.java:45)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.createParameterizedResultObject(FastResultSetHandler.java:415)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.createResultObject(FastResultSetHandler.java:384)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.createResultObject(FastResultSetHandler.java:365)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.getRowValue(FastResultSetHandler.java:261)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.handleRowValues(FastResultSetHandler.java:216)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(FastResultSetHandler.java:188)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.handleResultSets(FastResultSetHandler.java:154)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:57)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:70)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:57)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:259)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:132)
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:115)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:104)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:98)
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:354)
... 37 more
 Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:30)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.instantiateClass(DefaultObjectFactory.java:67)
... 59 more
```

Comment: Doesn't look like a PostgreSQL issue, way up in the Java stack. Consider posting the *full* exception stack trace though.

Comment: you are right. This is the iBatis-related issue.

Answer (score 9):

You need to have an empty constructor:

```
public Plugin() {

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Did you define the `Person` class as `abstract`?

This is not PostgreSQL or MyBatis issue in my opinion. The VM can't create instance of Person, but constructor args & types is correct.

```
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:30)
```

Comment: You probably mean the Plugin class. Yes, the Plugin class is defined as abstract.

Comment: Yes, I mean Plugin. You can't create an instance of an abstract class. It's impossible.

Comment: If you need create instances of known different types (PluginA, PluginB, etc) you can use `discriminator` in MyBatis resultMap. See for example: http://java.dzone.com/articles/ibatis-mybatis-discriminator or "MyBatis 3 User Guide"

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the "`abstract`" and

```
public Plugin(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
```

From the class